# Django: why does this if statement fail?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% for cat in p.categories.all %}
{{ cat }}
{% if cat == "Watches" %}
    <p>test</p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

p is an object provided by a view, with a manytomany relationship to "categories."  the `{{ cat }}` successfully displays `Watches`, which is the correct Category for the test cse I've been experimenting with.  Unfortunately, the if statement apparently fails, since the test paragraph isn't displayed.  I've been fiddling with this for 2 hours and trying every combination of conditional statements that I can think of yet I cannot figure out why this is failing

Comment: Is it exactly `"Watches"`, or is there possibly some whitespace in there?

Comment: I have double checked just  to be sure - no whitespace.

Comment: This is failing because your `Category` instance is never equal to the string `"Watches"`. Add a method to your `Category` model, such as `.is_watches` (or `.get_type`) and use them like: `{% if cat.is_watches %}` or `{% if cat.get_type == "Watches" %}` respectively.

Comment: What's the output of `type(cat)`?

Comment: @Saul Rennison, see my comment on Dave Castillo's answer, because your answer is basically the same as his.

Comment: @AlexL I'm not sure how you want me to use that...you realize this is in a template right, so only template tags apply?

Comment: @fildred13 Yes - I'm aware. You should stop debugging in your view, and use a shell - `python manage.py shell`. Then you can do `cat = p.categories.all[0]`, and then do `type(cat)` (you'll need an import somewhere). You'll see that it's not a string, although it renders as one. You can either compare a property (i.e. `cat.name == 'Watches'`) or `str(cat) == 'Watches'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On top of it being extremely slow, it is always best to handle as much of the "logic" in the backend.

Create a method that returns a boolean and test for it like so:

```
{% if cat.is_watches %}
    <p>test</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That may increase performance but I'm still left with the same python test in the backend, which is failing.  In the model the definition amounts to: `if "Watches" in self.categories.all(): return True`, which is still failing.

Comment: I ended up using `if self.categories.all().filter(name__exact='Watches'):` in case anyone wants to know what I used.

Comment: Yes sometimes is better to compare one attribute: `{% if cat.name == "Watches" %}` What does `__unicode__` in your model return?